# ODBC Driver in Advanced Installer

Tags: java, installation, odbc

IS there any "driver.dll" to connect to Oracle 10g in Advanced installer, i followed the guide but in that "myodbc3.dll " file is there, but that is for Sql not for Oracle, i tried with "sqora32.dll"and "sqoras32.dll" files, but when i am running the installation it being stucked at "installing ODBC Components" . what is the exact DLL file i need to Add for oracle 10g

Comment: What is an *"Advanced Installer"*?

Comment: Advanced Installer is the Tool for creating .exe files r .msi files

Comment: Why code in an x-platform language if targeting Windows only?  BTW - does the app. have a GUI?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the file "msorcl32.dll" as an Oracle 10g driver. Official downloads page is found here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/downloads/index.html

Comment: Thank you, but when i using it,i am getting 1639 error in Advanced installer8.1, when i run the installer, my installation showning this "command line error"